# Yii Integrate HP Object Storage plugin. Trouble with namespace

Tags: object, yii, namespaces, storage

I need to integrate the HP Object Storage plugin into my Yii project. I have downloaded the Hp Object Storage plugins in http://hpcloud.github.com/HPCloud-PHP/ and follow the tutorial is here
https://blog.hpcloud.com/working-object-storage-php

Here is the structure of my project

```
            /..
            /YiiBase.php
            /index.php
            /protected/..
            /protected/hpcloud/..
            /protected/hpcloud/Bootstrap.php
```

In the file /protected/config/main.php, I have already included the Bootstrap:

```
           spl_autoload_unregister(array('YiiBase','autoload')); //temporary skip yii autoload

            $basePath = dirname(__FILE__) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . '..';
            require_once $basePath . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'hpcloud' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'Bootstrap.php';

            use \HPCloud\Bootstrap;
            Bootstrap::useAutoloader();
            Bootstrap::useStreamWrappers();

            // Provide credentials
            $settings = array(
                'account' => YOUR_ACCOUNT_NUMBER,
                'secret' => YOUR_SECRET_KEY,
                'tenantid' => YOUR_TENANT_ID,
                'endpoint' => IDENTITY_SERVICES_URL,
            );
            Bootstrap::setConfiguration($settings);

            spl_autoload_register(array('YiiBase','autoload'));
```

But it threw the exception

```
            Fatal error: Class 'HPCloud\Storage\ObjectStorage\StreamWrapper' not found in D:\wamp\www\myproject\protected\hpcloud\Bootstrap.php on line 182
```

I opened Bootstrap.php to troubleshoot it

```
            public static function useStreamWrappers() {
                $swift = stream_wrapper_register( // error in line 182
                  \HPCloud\Storage\ObjectStorage\StreamWrapper::DEFAULT_SCHEME,
                  '\HPCloud\Storage\ObjectStorage\StreamWrapper'
                );

                $swiftfs = stream_wrapper_register(
                  \HPCloud\Storage\ObjectStorage\StreamWrapperFS::DEFAULT_SCHEME,
                  '\HPCloud\Storage\ObjectStorage\StreamWrapperFS'
                );

                return ($swift && $swiftfs);
            }
```

The namespaces and paths all are correct. I could not discover the cause of error.
If I leave the plugin with a simple file index.php alone (outside Yii project folder) upon following structure, it worked fine.

```
            \..
            \index.php
            \hpcloud\Bootstrap.php
```

The error just happed when I putted the plugin in Yii project, I think there are something wrong with namespace.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discover my problem now. It's all about case sensitive.
The namespace is "HPCloud" while plugin directory name is "hpcloud".